# Issue with threaded binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I am a newbie to data structures, and I was trying to learn threaded binary tree. My question is: after a tree has been threaded and if I need to add some nodes to the tree, should I un-thread it before adding nodes and then thread it again, or are there some better ways to add new nodes to a threaded binary tree? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to unthread the whole tree, because that takes O(n) operations in the number of nodes.

Instead, just correct the pointers in the nodes you "touch".

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_bst1.aspx#thread) that might help.